# How can I use the output signature of a functor in an interface file?

Tags: types, ocaml, reason

If I have an implementation (`.re`) file containing

```
module IntMap =
  Map.Make {
    type t = int;
    let compare = compare;
  };

type foo = IntMap.t string;
```

how can I add the signature of `foo` to the interface (`.rei`) file? In analogy with OCaml's

```ml
module IntMap = Map.S with type key = int
type foo = string IntMap.t
```

I expected it to be

```
module IntMap =
  Map.S {
    type t = int;
  };

type foo = IntMap.t string;
```

but that results in a syntax error at `{`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the root cause of your problem is that the OCaml code you posted is not valid. It should be

```
module IntMap: Map.S with type key = int
```

The Reason equivalent then is

```
module IntMap: Map.S with type key = int;
type foo = IntMap.t string;
```

Not very different :)

Also, in case you're not aware of it, [reason-tools](https://github.com/reasonml/reason-tools) is a great tool that will convert between Reason and OCaml for you. It does require valid input though ;)

Comment: Ah, thanks. My mistakes were 1) referring to [an invalid example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17241690) of OCaml and 2) attempting to [convert via Try Reason](https://reasonml.github.io/try/?ocaml=LYewJgrgNgpgBASQHYBcCyBDADgLjprAOgGU4B3ASxQAs4UBPLeAaxnrgF44LUg), which reports a syntax error in the corrected OCaml.